# Function to compare dates in php doesn't work

Tags: php

I built this function that is supposed to compare dates and return a boolean.
When I run it though, it breaks, the page stops.

the function:

```
 public function compare_date_outlook($creation, $modification) {
        $creation_date =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $creation);
        $creation_date = $creation_date->format( 'Y-m-d');
        $modification_date =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $modification);
        $modification_date = $modification_date->format( 'Y-m-d');   
        $date = new \DateTime( 'yesterday' );
        $date->setTime( 0, 0, 0 );
        $yesterday = $date->format( 'Y-m-d');

           if (($creation || $modification) == $yesterday)
           {
               return TRUE;
           }

           else {
               return FALSE;
           }
        }
```

How I call it:

```
if ( compare_date_outlook($a['creationDate'], $a['lastModifiedDate']) === TRUE)
```

The format of the date:

```
 $a['creationDate'] = "2017-09-08T13:26:11.4354775Z";
```

It stops right in the beginnig:

```
$creation_date =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $creation);
```

Comment: Since it's a public function, aren't you supposed to refer to it as $this->

Comment: `if (($creation || $modification) == $yesterday)`???   `if (($creation == $yesterday || $modification == $yesterday)`.... but don't compare the formatted strings.... compare the DateTime objects themselves.... they're deliberately written to be directly comparable

Comment: @Akintunde where do you think $this will refer? That's not about function itself.

Comment: @TMA have you got any error thrown upon script stop? Please, attach if you got any.

Comment: @MarkBaker that's an improvement, thanks, the issue is, when I debug, i get inside the function, it just stops in the first line

Comment: @BogdanLapchenkov no I haven't, I'll try to, I am new to php

Comment: The format mask seems to create a DateTime object well enough from the sample date you've provided ([demo](https://3v4l.org/WocKj))

Comment: will you try `\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $creation);`?

Comment: Is this function literally just to check if something was created or modified yesterday (at some point)?

Comment: @RossWilson, yes

Comment: @B.Desai it worked!! Why does it need the /? Please add it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @TMA by the way, try using Carbon package [link](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)
It provides quite fancy wrapper for DateTime class, and as I can remember it can complete your task "from the box"

Comment: Personally, I'd write it as [this](https://3v4l.org/PSTdb)

Comment: @TMA it didn't work because you were in another namespace than `\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have other namespace. So you need to add `\` before global methods/classes when you are in different namespace

see doc here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

```
public function compare_date_outlook($creation, $modification) {
        $creation_date =  \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $creation);
        $creation_date = $creation_date->format( 'Y-m-d');
        $modification_date =  \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $modification);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
function compare_date_outlook($creation, $modification)
{
    $today = (new \Datetime())->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $yesterday = (new \Datetime('yesterday'))->setTime(0, 0, 0);

    $creation_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $creation);
    $modification_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $modification);

    return ($creation_date >= $yesterday && $creation_date < $today) ||
        ($modification_date >= $yesterday && $modification_date < $today);
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the format masks as `'Y-m-d|+'` to force time part to `00:00:00`, it's sometimes a useful trick

Comment: @MarkBaker Cheers for that! Definitely a handy one to know :)